# Ruby script to read output from alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I have setup an alias in `/etc/aliases` so that each time an email comes in to a specific address, the text of the email is sent to a Ruby script.  Like so:

example: `|/etc/smrsh/my_script.rb`

I need to know how to read the piped data in my Ruby script..
I have written a simple Perl script that can read the data.. just can't figure out how to do it in Ruby.

Here is the relevant lines in the Perl script:

```
my $fout = "/tmp/email.out";

open( EM, ">$fout" );

while( <> )  {
    chomp;
    print EM "$_\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `STDIN` to read your pided data. The equivalent of your Perl code would be something like:

```
out = File.open("/tmp/email.out", "a+")
STDIN.each do |line|
  out.puts line
end
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you.  As a side note, in order to get the alias to work properly, I had to create symlink to the ruby binary in /etc/smrsh and then define the alias as:

my_alias: "|/etc/smrsh/ruby /etc/smrsh/my_script.rb"

And that did it!  Thanks!

Comment: help me look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072489/ruby-script-sending-received-email-as-sms?noredirect=1#comment59792534_36072489